# Make Rails ignore daylight saving time when displaying a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, dst

I have a date stored in UTC in my Rails app and am trying to display it to a user who has `"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` as their timezone. The problem is that rails keeps converting it to **Eastern Daylight Time (EDT)** so midnight is being displayed as **8am** when it should be **7am**. Is there anyway to prevent the DST conversion?

```
>> time = DateTime.parse("2013-08-26T00:00:00Z")
=> Mon, 26 Aug 2013 00:00:00 +0000 
>> time.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
=> Sun, 25 Aug 2013 20:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

### Update

I eventually went with a twist on @zeantsoi 's approach. I'm not a huge fan of adding too many rails helpers so I extended active support's `TimeWithZone` class.

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def no_dst
    if self.dst?
      self - 1.hour
    else
      self
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can do `time.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").no_dst`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper that utilizes the [`dst?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-dst-3F) method on `TimeZone` to check whether the passed timezone is currently in DST. If it is, then subtract an hour from the supplied `DateTime` instance:

```
# helper function
module TimeConversion
  def no_dst(datetime, timezone)
    Time.zone = timezone

    if Time.zone.now.dst?
        return datetime - 1.hour
    end

    return datetime
  end
end
```

Then, render the adjusted (or non-adjusted) time in your view:

```
# in your view
<%= no_dst(DateTime.parse("2013-08-26T00:00:00Z"), 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)') %>
#=> Sun, 25 Aug 2013 19:00:00 EDT -04:00
```