# Ignore DST on Rails Timzone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I receive time-stamped data from some equipments, who are configured with a timezone (`Europe/Paris`, for example).

Problem is that some of them are not aware of DST (Daylight Saving Time) change, and some are, which causes us to have a offset problem when we're in DST (like right now).

Today I have the following code to parse this data:

```rb
def parse_timestamp(timestamp, format=nil)
  case timestamp
  when String then @timezone.local_to_utc(Time.strptime(timestamp, format))
  when Integer then @timezone.local_to_utc(@timezone.at(timestamp))
  else raise Etl::Parsers::TimeConversionError, "Can't parse timestamp #{timestamp.inspect}"
  end
end
```

The `@timezone` variable is created like this: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[timezone]`.

I'm looking for a way to ignore the DST when the equipment have a `@dst` property (let's say) that tells wether its timestamps are DST aware.

Comment: Why are the timestamps using a local time zone at all? Timestamps should always be serialized in UTC, IMO. And surely if you ignore DST then you'll get the wrong result for the equipment that *does* know about DST changes. Any chance you could reconfigure things to serialize the timestamp in UTC unconditionally?

Comment: @JonSkeet I wish I could do that. These equipments are from different manufactures of differents countries. Some of them send us information on UTC, some on Timezone with DST and some without. It's not up to me how they generate their data.

Comment: Could you give an example of the various timestamps you receive and the expected conversion / output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` has a useful `dst?` method to check if the time is within Daylight Savings Time for the specified time zone:

```
Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'    # => 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
Time.zone.parse("2012-5-30").dst?           # => true
Time.zone.parse("2012-11-30").dst?          # => false
```

You can read more at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-dst-3F

So you can just check if time is within DST, or extend `TimeWithZone`, as explained here [Make Rails ignore daylight saving time when displaying a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541571/make-rails-ignore-daylight-saving-time-when-displaying-a-date) by @zeantsoi:

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def no_dst
    self.dst? ? self - 1.hour : self
  end
end
```

and use it this way always getting the time without DST:

```
time.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").no_dst
```

Comment: This seems promising. I'll try to implement something like it and get back to you.

Comment: @Vasili how exactly did you extend ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone in your app? Did you put it in as an initializer somewhere?

Comment: @Doug exactly. Just create some file in `config/initializers` and put the code inside.