# Can't set timezone using abbreviation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport

I can't set timezone on Rails using its abbreviation, for example:

```
>> Time.zone = 'BRT'
ArgumentError: Invalid Timezone: BRT
        from /home/braulio/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:61:in `rescue in find_zone!'
        from /home/braulio/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:53:in `find_zone!'
        from /home/braulio/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:37:in `zone='
        from (irb):14
        from /home/braulio/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /home/braulio/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /home/braulio/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This is necessary as some systems (android and some browsers) report timezone using the abbreviation.
The list of abbreviations can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations

Comment: What would you want to happen with ambiguous abbreviations? Basically, you should avoid using abbreviations as a way of *specifying* a time zone. There are various ways of detecting a time zone in JavaScript, if that's helpful to you...

Comment: Hey Jon, yeah, jstz is reporting timezone using abbreviations, see https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/issue/116/dont-use-abbreviations-to-report-timezone. Do you recommend another library?

Comment: I recommend you find a different one, yes. I don't have any specific recommendations, but I know there are many available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jstimezone was reporting timezone using abbreviations. It is also quite buggy and unmaintained (https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/issues?status=new&status=open). It is simpler to just use standard javascript:

```
var offset = - new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60
```

Then call on document ready:

```
$.cookie("browser.tzoffset", offset, { expires: 30, path: '/' })
```

Then in rails use `around_filter` in `ApplicationController`:

```
  def set_time_zone
    return yield unless (utc_offset = cookies['browser.tzoffset']).present?
    utc_offset = utc_offset.to_i
    gmt_offset = if utc_offset == 0 then nil elsif utc_offset > 0 then -utc_offset else "+#{-utc_offset}" end
    Time.use_zone("Etc/GMT#{gmt_offset}"){ yield }
  rescue ArgumentError
    yield
  end
```

This localizes all dates for users, independently where he/she is. In Brazil we have multiple timezones, for example.

PS: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[utc_offset.to_i]` can't be used as it uses DST, see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20504

PS: You can also use moment: `moment.parseZone(Date.now()).utcOffset()/60` or `moment().format('zz')`

Comment: Uhhh...  jsTimeZoneDetect does not return abbreviations.  It returns time zones, such as `America/New_York`.  If it's returning an abbreviation, you should raise that as a bug.

Comment: Also, using `getTimeZoneOffset` is not appropriate for time zone detection, as it only returns the offset from the `Date` object that it's called on.  Since you are calling it on `new Date()`, then it returns the *current* offset for the time zone where the code is running.  You cannot just take an offset and map it back to a time zone, as many time zones share the same offsets, and use them at different times of the year.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: matt, the important in this answer is to localize dates from database to presentation to an specific user. So the user's timezone isn't important.

Comment: maybe you could use `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolved.timeZone` ?

Comment: @Andy `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolved.timeZone` is returning timezone abbreviations on some android devices with Chrome.

Comment: @brauliobo does `var offset = - new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60` not cause any problem within DST ?

Comment: @medBo yeah, it will be the real offset from the user time to UTC, so no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use around_filter.
Put this in `before_action`

`Time.zone = "Etc/GMT#{gmt_offset}"`

(Time.zone is thread local. It's safe to change.)